# Android - Custom Lists

Tags: android, custom-lists

I am not sure about how do we custom lists is android 2.2 or any later

I want a basic activity that can make custom lists by layout inflater

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "make custom lists", huh? Care to expand?

Comment: what do you mean by custom list? is it you want to create a custom listview or custom adaptor to display the listview. can you elaborate what is your need?

Comment: is it a custom listview,in which u can add elements?or u meant an adapter?plese specify...edit the question

Comment: i have a layout that i want to use in my list or in other words i dont want to use LayoutInflater!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, so, here an example on how to show a list dialog:

```
/* create the dialog */
final AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

/* create the list of items to show on listbox */
String [] myList = {"A","B","C","D","E"};

/* create an adapter to control how the listbox should appear */
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
  (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice,myList);

/* the item that will be initially selected on listbox */
int selected = 0;

/* inform the dialog about our items and create an onClick function to listen for
   user inputs */
dlg.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter,selected,
  new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      // selected item is myList[which];
      dialog.dismiss();
    }
  });

/* change the dialog title */
dlg.setTitle("My dialog");

/* show the dialog */
dlg.show();
```

This will show a dialog with radio buttons for the user to select one of them. When the user perform a click on the item, the onClick funcion will be called. The selected item is pointed by the 'which' argument. The 'dlg' object offers other ways to show the list of items, allowing you to show items without the radio button, create some buttons on the dialog and things like this. Just play with object's methods to see the differences.

Comment: no sorry i dont want that i want a list that uses my own layout!